# Is there a quantifier elimination functionality in CVC5 or CVC4 (I am using Python API)?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, quantifiers, cvc4

I am using CVC5 in Python and realize that I need something that does the equivalent to the following Z3-Py code:

```
    t = Tactic("qe")
    phi = Goal()
    phi.add(Exists(var_list, psi))
    phi_qe = t(phi)
    #print(phi_qe)
```

That is: given a formula `phi`, a list of variables `var_list` and a formula `psi`, containing variables of `var_list`, I apply quantifier-elimination method `t` to `phi` to obtain `phi_qe`, whenever `phi_qe` is a simplified formula or `True/False`.

Is there this kind of `t` quantifier elimination in CVC5? I mean, I guess the tool uses quantifier elimination for performing `sat/unsat` queries, but I would like to know if there is such `t` function call from the API.

In case not, is there such functionality in CVC4?

Comment: Possibly.. I haven't personally used it, but check out: https://cvc5.github.io/docs/cvc5-1.0.2/api/python/base/solver.html?highlight=eliminate#cvc5.Solver.getQuantifierElimination Please report your experiences with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will experiment a bit :))